# How to store the output from series.iteritems()?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Input:

```
Occ2 = df_demog_ds['GenderSelect'].value_counts()
for index, val in Occ2.iteritems():
  print(index, val, "-", (val*100/1263),"%")
```

Output:

```
Male 1089 - 86.22327790973871 %
Female 168 - 13.30166270783848 %
A different identity 6 - 0.4750593824228028 %
```

Occ2 is a pd.series. df_demog_ds is a dataframe [LINK](https://www7.zippyshare.com/v/IhcLQsKZ/file.html). I am trying to directly store the output in a list or a tuple but it's not working out. I tried making empty lists and storing there but that didn't help.

```
testx = ['0', '0', '0']
testy = ['0', '0', '0']
Occ2 = df_demog_ds['GenderSelect'].value_counts()
for index, val in Occ2.iteritems():
  testx = index
  testy = val
print(testx)
print(testy)
```

I also tried to store Occ2.iteritems() but that didn't work too

I feel the problem is very easy to solve but I can't do it with my limited knowledge. I'm a noob in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just look at these two lines:

```
testx = ['0', '0', '0']
testx = index
```

What these do is to create a list of three strings, then throw that list away and make `testx` refer to the value of `index` (e.g. the string `"A different identity"`).

It seems like what you're trying to do is to create a list containing the strings contained in all the `index` values, not just one.  For that, you should do this:

```
testx = []
# ...
for index, val in Occ2.iteritems():
  testx.append(index)
```